# Logging all hive sql statements as the execute from one .hql file

Tags: shell, logging, hive, beeline

I have one .hql with multiple hive sql statements that I am executing via beeline hive in a .sh file. Is there anyway to print the sql statements to the logs as they execute? I tried modifying some of the hive log settings in the beeline command but was unable to get each hql statement to show up in the logs.

Comment: `beeline` is a thin Java client; the verbosity of its logs is controlled by a Log4J2 properties file, cf. https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/beeline/src/main/resources/beeline-log4j2.properties >> try bumping the **global** level to `DEBUG` and then, if you spot the exact Java class that you want to log verbosely, set a **specific** level for that class only and revert the global settings to `INFO`.

Comment: Note that the Log4J2 properties enable you to log directly to a file, instead of the pre-set `Console` sink.

Comment: Note also that understanding Log4J2 from scratch is a challenge -- especially since it has changed so much from the older Log4J1.x (used by older Hive versions i.e. V0.x and V1.x, also still used by the rest of the Hadoop stack)